# Udev rule interfering with gnome automount

Tags: linux, fedora, mount, udev, removable-storage

I'm trying to make an udev rule to backup the contents of my USB key using Rsync.
My problem is the following

- If I name the rule 99-nameoftherule.rule, the script is ran, but I do not see my USB key in gnome and the backup doesn't finish
- If I name the rule 00-nameoftherule.rule, the script isn't ran but the USB key is shown on gnome

Here is the udev rule

```
SUBSYSTEMS=="block", KERNEL=="sd?1",SYMLINK+="cleart" , ACTION=="add", ENV{ID_SERIAL_SHORT}=="0019E001EA29C031043F161D", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/sync_relay.sh"
```

sync_relay.sh :

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Device : $1" >> /tmp/log_sync.log
/usr/local/bin/sync.sh &
```

sync.sh :

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Démarrage de la copie" >> /tmp/log_sync.log
sleep 5
mkdir /run/cleart &>> /tmp/log_sync.log
mount /dev/cleart /run/cleart &>> /tmp/log_sync.log
rsync -r -t -v --delete --progress -s /run/cleart 192.168.0.47::cle_usb_art &>> /tmp/log_sync.log
echo "Copie terminée" >> /tmp/log_sync.log
umount /run/cleart >> /tmp/log_sync.log 2>>&1
```

I've also tried to copy directly /run/media/konfiot/USB/ with Rsync but with no luck, this time, it seems that gnome waits for the script to finish in order to mount the key, so rsync fails because /run/media/konfiot/USB/ doesn't exists

I'm running fedora 19

Thanks in advance for any help

EDIT : I've just updated to fedora 20 (Gnome 3.10), with no luck